# Xcode 6.1 different "deployment info" section for duplicated target

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode6

So,
I have an universal project
[image]

The "deployment info" section looks like this:
[image]

I then duplicate the target
[image]

I expect the two targets to be identical and in fact they seem the same in everything, but one detail is different in the duplicated one:
[image]

the duplicated target has 2 tabs to choose different options for iPad and Iphone; this makes really sense because with universal I can choose the check different stuff.
The original target seems to show only the iPhone options though. I know I can change iPad's options elsewhere but I can't understand why this is different

Now the question is: am I missing something?
Are the targets really identical or am I doing something wrong?
Is it an Xcode bug?

Everything works properly as it should, the targets are identical, but I am a little afraid there could be some problems in future.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I've exactly the same problem after duplicating a target. Everything seems to work but it is weird... Have you found what's the caus ?

Comment: No, I think is just a bug. Everything works anyway.. Probably is a not documented feature;)

Comment: Yep. Good to know that we are not the only ones anyway ;)

Comment: I'm having this same problem. I have the separate `iPhone` and `iPad` buttons in the original target, but those are replaced with the dropdown menu in the copied target. I just found this odd and it didn't worry me, until I noticed some differences between the two targets in how some specific Autolayout UIs are being handled (with the second target having bugs when running the exact same code that works perfectly for the original target). I would love to know what's going on here and why the built apps for the two different targets don't behave the same. :-(

Answer (score 21):

I found the attribute which affect the display behavior of Xcode deployment info:

In the PBXProject section of project.pbxproj file, there are lines looks like:

```
            TargetAttributes = {
                22CFA0081BE46E9A00A89E90 = {
                    CreatedOnToolsVersion = 7.2;
                };
            };
```

If this attribute exists in the project, the Xcode will not display "iPhone" and "iPad" buttons . Just remove these lines, then the buttons will show.

This should be a bug of Xcode7.2

Comment: Newly created universal projects (in Xcode 7.2.1) do not have the iPhone/iPad buttons. Are they supposed to?

Comment: On any "CreatedOnToolsVersion" you can simply remove it, and it work again !

Comment: Thank you! I had the same issue with Xcode 7.3. One target allowed me to select iPad and iPhone separately, my original (oldest) target didn't. Removing all occurrences of `CreatedOnToolsVersion = x.x;` fixed this.

Comment: project.pbxproj file remove CreatedOnToolsVersion lines  TargetAttributes = {
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX = {
                CreatedOnToolsVersion = 8.3; //that
            };
        };

Comment: This is still happening in Xcode 10.1 (10B61) :( but the fix still works!

Answer (score 2):

I found this same problem today in my project.
But I needed a solution because it was not respecting my orientation settings on the original target when using an iPad.

I made a copy of the already duplicated target.  This solution worked, but I abandoned it to limit my risk to our production build settings.

I ended up just modifying the appropriate ProjectX-Info.plist file
Locating the "Supported Interface orientations (iPad)" key
and adding all 4 orientations.
(Replacing "ProjectX" with your Target)

I am using Xcode 7.0.1 (7A1001) and hope it is fixed in a future release

Comment: This other question has a visual of how to implement this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536616/swift-allow-rotation-on-ipad-only