# Lock orientation only on IPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I lock orientation only on IPhone

**Detect the device is iPhone**

```
if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
    switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
    case 1136:
        print("iPhone 5,5S,5C")
    case 1334:
        print("iPhone 6,6S,7,8")
    case 2208:
        print("iPhone 6+,6S+,7+,8+")
    case 2436:
        print("iPhone X")
    default:
        print("unknown")
    }
}
```

I use this code but he is lock orientation on iPhone and on iPad

In ViewDidLoad:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait.rawValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set this in info.plist

Perhaps this answers your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30537068/8364981

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17766492)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The answer referenced includes a screenshot. Would I be allowed to copy that?